# system.access.violation exception while calling c++ function from a thread in c#

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, exception, dllimport

i am importing c++ function from a dll to my winform c# app:

```
[DllImport(@"eyeWhere.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int Eye_GetPositionS(string filename, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 9)] double[] sensors);
```

when i call the function from the constructor its working fine.

the problem is when i am calling it from a new thread opened within the
"fleck websocket server" [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck), "onMessage" Action,
then it throws the "system.access.violation" exception.

i managed to narrow down the problem to the double array that i am passing,
it seems like the pointer to it is corrupted.

i cant find the source of the problem one thing is sure the function from the dll is working as i tested it.

function call(two stages):

1. open new thread within "fleck":

`socket.OnMessage = message =>
            {Thread locationThread = new Thread( unused => processLocation(fileName,socket,sensorsList,sensors) );
                                locationThread.Start();}`

2. the actual function:

`private void processLocation(string fileName, IWebSocketConnection sock, List<Sensor> sensorsList, double[] sensors)
        { 
           int map_position = Eye_GetPositionS(fileName,sensors);

                string locationString = "floor:1,mx:" + (map_position / 10000) +    ",my:" + (map_position % 10000);
                // send location string to user
                sock.Send(LOCATION_CODE + "-" + locationString);}`

the interface is:

`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Eye_GetPositionS(const wchar_t *fname_mob, double sensors[9], int &map_x, int &map_y)`

i am not passing the two last arguments (int&) as agreed with the man who wrote the dll.

Comment: Show how you call the function.

Comment: Perhaps you aren't allowed to call the function from a thread other than the main thread. You should work this out by writing some C++ code so that you are sure that the p/invoke is not confounding. I mean, if the p/invoke is wrong, how can you expect us to help? You only showed one half of the interface.

Comment: the problem is that i don't have access to the code inside the dll its a part of project that i am doing for a startup company. i can say that i worked with a Similar function within the same dll and it worked fine under the same workflow.

Comment: You may as well give up if you don't know the interface. Or do you mean you don't have the implementation. If you have the interface, can't we see it?

Comment: i added the interface, and you are  right i dont have the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not passing the two last arguments (`int&`) as agreed with the man who wrote the DLL.

Well, there's the problem. You cannot omit parameters. It should be:

```
[DllImport(@"eyeWhere.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int Eye_GetPositionS(
    string filename, 
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 9)] 
    double[] sensors,
    ref int map_x,
    ref int map_y
);
```

You simply cannot omit these parameters, no matter what the guy who wrote the DLL says. Perhaps he means that the parameters are really `int*` and you can pass `nullptr`.

I've used `ref` for these parameters, but perhaps they should be `out`. You presumably know which is appropriate.

Likewise I'm guessing at the intent of the `sensors` parameter. If the data flows out rather than in, then use `Out`. If the data flows in both directions, use `[In, Out, ...]`.

Comment: are you sure it should be "Out" insted of "In" before the "MarshalAs" ?

Comment: I've no idea. That's a question that you need to answer! Which way does the data flow?

Comment: ok, i got it sorry its "In" sensors is passed into the function. how can i pass a null pointer to the last to integers address?

Comment: You cant pass null to a C++ reference

Comment: If it is int* rather than int& then you can declare params as IntPtr and pass IntPtr.Zero. I sense confusion though. Perhaps on the part of the dll developer.